# Recommend best approach on my situation (Multitenancy vs Single Tenant with abp)

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, aspnetboilerplate

I'm modeling a kind of billing app that involve 3 main roles on the system, Insurer, Medical Provider and Analyst, i choose aspnetboilerplate application framework to build my solution. I'm trying to choose Single vs Multitenancy from my constraints.

1. Medical Provider, need to enroll Patients, that can't be seen by other Providers
2. Medical Provider, have a manager account, created by the manager of the whole system, but can create other users under its "tenant"
3. Email are taken as username and should be unique across the system not per Medical Provider.
4. Insurers, review medical claims from Medical Provider on its own Portal.
5. Analyst audit claims before Insurers
6. Admin users create admin Medical Providers and enroll Insurers.

Is the Multitenancy approach the best on this situation or single tenant fit better when using aspnetboilerplate for this?

Comment: This is not a question. This is business requirements. You should research, try to do something then if you have any particular code problem, you can ask. But where is the code? I don't see any.

Comment: My concern is about, what to choose in ABP due to there are a lot of constraint if we use Tenant but also a lot of features we lose if not use it. What someone recommend, i already know how to implement the features is just a matter of what to choose based on well use of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

With these requirements, you should Abp multitenancy approach. In Abp, when you use [IMustHaveTenant](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#imusthavetenant-interface) interface, Abp can automatically filter your query response based on your logged-in user's tenant.

```
public class Product : Entity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //...other properties
}
```

> This way, ASP.NET Boilerplate knows that this is a tenant-specific
> entity and **automatically isolates** the entities of a tenant from other
> tenants.

You can get more informatin from their [multi-tenancy documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy).

> **What Is Multi-Tenancy?**
>
> "Software Multitenancy refers to a software architecture in which a
> single instance of a software runs on a server and serves *multiple
> tenants*. A tenant is a group of users who share a common access with
> specific privileges to the software instance. With a multitenant
> architecture, a software application is designed to provide every
> tenant a *dedicated share of the instance including its data*,
> configuration, user management, tenant individual functionality and
> non-functional properties. Multitenancy contrasts with multi-instance
> architectures, where separate software instances operate on behalf of
> different tenants" (Wikipedia)
>
> **Host vs Tenant**
>
> We define two terms used in a multi-tenant system:
>
> **Tenant:** A customer which has its own users, roles, permissions,
> settings... and uses the application completely isolated from other
> tenants. A multi-tenant application will have one or more tenants. If
> this is a CRM application, different tenants also have their own
> accounts, contacts, products and orders. So when we say a 'tenant
> user', we mean a user owned by a tenant.
>
> **Host:** The Host is singleton
> (there is a single host). The Host is responsible for creating and
> managing tenants. A 'host user' is at a higher level and independent
> from all tenants and can control them.